'The exam is very difficult so I don't think ___ can pass it'

The exam is very difficult so I don't think __ can pass it.
A. anybody
B. everybody
C. no one
D. somebody

Semantically, I infer the author wanted to emphasize that no one can pass the exam, because they used very difficult .So A is more possible than the others.
But this is just an inference, so some people may select B because not all can pass it also makes sense.
C is not right.
But after googling, there are versions with "...I don't think somebody...", so I want to make sure whether this is a possible answer too.

Both A and B are possible. Not the others.

B is certainly grammatical, but I think you're supposed to infer the answer is A - none of the students pass, rather than B - not all of the students pass. But it depends how the question is worded, what is being examined, etc. If you're asked "which is best" or "which is most likely" then A; if it's "which is grammatical" then A or B.

Technically D is also possible if you are speaking about individual's ability to pass the exam in a derogatory way. Usually with an emphasis on "somebody".  In colloquial spoken English, if two people are discussing a third one's shortcomings,  it is quite common to refer to them as "somebody" or "someone" when both know who is meant. For example "Somebody isn't going to pass the exam"

Please [edit] your question to tell us what you already know about indefinite pronouns, and what research have you done to try and answer the question yourself. As it stands, this question is off-topic because you haven't shown your work.

Also, this is a poorly written question because it has three correct answers. If you're just confused by the multiple possible answers, you're right, and the teacher is wrong.

"The exam is very difficult so I don't think somebody can pass it" is definitely wrong. "The exam is very difficult so I don't think no one can pass it" is a construction you wiill hear often from (less articulate) native speakers but even they, if asked, would probably recognise it as wrong. A and B are both possible correct answers.

@gotube ♦ I have edited it.


A. anybody This is correct and probably the answer they are looking for. It means "The exam is so difficult that there is not a single person who can pass it".
B. everybody Grammatically correct. It means "The exam is so difficult that there will be somebody who does not pass it." (not everybody passes it). It would however be unusual because it is likely that there will be someone who does not pass even if the exam is easy, so the sentence doesn't make real sense.
C. nobody Wrong. The classic double-negative which is not allowed in English.
D. somebody Technically grammatically correct. There is a usage in which "somebody" means "a person in general". The exam is so difficult that people won't pass it. However in similar sentences "somebody" would not be correct, and even here "anybody" would be much better.


Regarding option D: you use "somebody" when you are thinking about a particular person, but you don't know who it is:

Somebody stole my bike
I don't think that somebody in my neighbourhood stole it.

In your sentence, you are not thinking about a particular person: you are thinking about the outcome for each and every person who takes the exam, so "somebody" is not an appropriate option.
If you think that, out of all of those people, nobody will pass the exam, you say

I don't think that anybody will pass the exam.

If you think that some people will fail, you say

I don't think that everybody will pass the exam.

Option C is possible, as a response to somebody else's assertion:

Person A: I think that no-one can pass this exam.
Person B: I don't think that no-one can pass the exam, but I expect that a few people will fail.


Option D is possible like this:  "The exam is so difficult, I don't think somebody can actually pass it."

@swmcdonnell can you provide some reference to justify your assertion?

My reference is that it is something I wold say. It doesn't violate any rules.
